# Is it important to map the physical interaction of users with the design requirements of the intended interface?

Tags: human-computer-interface

Is it important to map the physical interaction of users with the design requirements of the intended interface? Why can't we perform both of these activities in isolation? Give reasons for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Yes, it is important to map the interactions of users to the requirements of the intended interface. This would be especially true where the interface design/requirements that you mention "precede" observations of user interactions on an interactive/incremental implementation of that design.

Q2: Yes, we can perform both of those activities in isolation. (observing/documenting the user interactions and documenting the requirements of the interface.) Observation of users with a current application is, in fact, one valid technique for eliciting requirements. In that sense, you might observe several interactions on a current interface that do not end up mapping to a requirement of a new interface.